# Как заполнить вложенный список определенным значением в python?

Tags: python, python-3.x

У меня есть список со вложенными списками, довольно глубокий. И мне потребовалось создать список с такой же структурой, но заполненный одним значением.

**Исходный список:**

```py
field = [
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [[2, 3, 4], [1, 2]], 3],
    [1, 2, 2],
    4
]
```

**Что хочу получить:**

```py
field2 = fillDeepList(field2, 0);

# [
#     [[0, 0, 0],[0, 0, 0],[[0, 0, 0],[0, 0]],0],
#     [0, 0, 0],
#     0
# ]
```

Я поискал, но ничего дельного не нашел. Нашел только то, что в модуле `copy` есть функция `deepcopy` для копирования вложенных списков.

По итогу я написал вот такую функцию:

```py
def fillDeepList(field, value):
    if isinstance(field, Iterable):
        return [fillDeepList(i, value) for i in field]
    else:
        return value
```

Она вроде бы нормально работает. **Может что-то подобное уже есть в каком-нибудь модуле в коробке?**

Comment: Вы бы привели пример исходного списка и желаемого результата.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Ничего так и не нашел, получилось только немного подсократить запись:

```
from collections.abc import Iterable

field = [[[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [[2, 3, 4], [1, 2]], 3], [1, 2, 2], 4]


def deep_fill(items, value):
    return [deep_fill(x, value) for x in items] if isinstance(items, Iterable) else value


filled_field = deep_fill(field, 0)
print(filled_field)
# [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0]], 0], [0, 0, 0], 0]
```

Answer (score 1):

Рекурсией обходим структуру, меняя значение:

```
def deep_fill(items: list, value):
    for i in range(len(items)):
        if isinstance(items[i], list):
            deep_fill(items[i], value)
        else:
            items[i] = value

field = [
    [[1, 2, 3], [2, 3, 4], [[2, 3, 4], [1, 2]], 3],
    [1, 2, 2],
    4
]

deep_fill(field, 0)
print(field)
# [[[0, 0, 0], [0, 0, 0], [[0, 0, 0], [0, 0]], 0], [0, 0, 0], 0]
```